# Count sub_lists length in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

My python is 3 ver.
I have a list, which contains sub lists, like:

```
L=[[1,2], [3,4], [5,6,7]]
```

I want to calculate length of all sub_list and write down them to a dictionary, like this:

```
D={2:2,3:1}
```

that is, we have 2 lists which have length 2, and 1 list which have the length 3.

It can be done by for-loop + check D[key] is exist or not.

May be there is some 'pythonic way?'

Comment: Yes. You can use `for loop`. Have you tried something?

Comment: can you show your work for this please?

Comment: Do you have anything working before you attempt to write it in a pythonic way? Also, I would think you should have 1 list mapped to a length of 3 (your example is backwards)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `defaultdict` where you store the length of the list as the key, and just increment each value by 1 every time to get a matching list length:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(int)
L = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6,7]]

for li in L:
    d[len(li)] += 1

print(d) # defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {2: 2, 3: 1})
```

Or use `Counter` from `collections` as well:

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter(len(li) for li in L)

print(c) # Counter({2: 2, 3: 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over the list, and check that the length exists as key or not. If it exists, increment the value by 1, else add the value as 1. Below is the sample code.

```
>>> L = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6,7]]
>>> my_len_dict = {}
>>> for item in L:
...     item_length = len(item)
...     if item_length in my_len_dict:
...         my_len_dict[item_length] += 1
...     else:
...         my_len_dict[item_length] = 1
...
>>> my_len_dict
{2: 2, 3: 1}
```